# Two apps first emitting to another in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The following code is not sending back the response, any ideas why?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app1 = express(),
    app2 = express();

app1.use(function(req, res, next) {
    app2.emit('request', req, res);
});

app2.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hi from app2");
});

app1.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Express application (the thing returned by `express()`) is not a HTTP [`Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server); it does not emit or consume `request` events.

It is actually a request handler function – it's what you attach to a `Server`'s `request` event.  (That's done internally when you call `app.listen()`: a new http `Server` is created and the app is attached to its `request` event.)

So what you need  to do is just invoke the handler function:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app1 = express(),
    app2 = express();

app1.use(function(req, res, next) {
    app2(req, res);
});

app2.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hi from app2");
});

app1.listen(80);
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem ) But since I'm new to Node/Express I didn't get why it works this way. I got the idea of emitting from the sources of [connect-vhost](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/vhost.js) and [express-vhost](https://github.com/vast-eng/express-vhost/blob/master/lib/vhost.js) and it seems like they calling the emit function from app instances. Is this line `if ('function' == typeof server) return server(req, res, next);` doing the trick?

Comment: @Acute: Yes.  I believe the `server.emit(...)` is a compatibility thing.

Comment: One more confusing thing: how can a function (app2) have properties? I mean calling the `app2` as a function `app2()` and accessing it's properties like `app2.get()`

Comment: All right, I've just found out that functions in JS can have properties %)

Comment: @Acute: In JavaScript, [functions are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) and thus can have properties.